# Can't create a mongodb single instance

Tags: mongodb

Hello i am new to mongodb i have created config file and configered it and created a root user

[image]

if i want to see collections in admin command it is showing like this

[image]

please help me to solve with this issue. and help me is any thing wrong in config file

Comment: Please do not post images for text information

Comment: See [userAdminAnyDatabase](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#mongodb-authrole-userAdminAnyDatabase) which privileges are granted with this role. `listCollections` is not included. May grant role `dbAdminAnyDatabase` or even `root` role.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two things you can do to fix this problem:

1. Perform [db.auth()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.auth/) to authenticate your access
2. Use [db.grantRolesToUser()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.grantRolesToUser/#mongodb-method-db.grantRolesToUser) to grant the [roles](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/built-in-roles/) with [listCollections](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#mongodb-authaction-listCollections) command to the current user

Comment: I don't think it is smart to grant privileges to [Built-In Roles](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/built-in-roles/). Either create user-defined roles or grant appropriated roles to the user.

Comment: I have did db.auth and used db.grantRolesToUser() but it is saying that listCollections is not found

Comment: @Durgaprasad Apologies, listCollections is not actually a role. The list of roles is here[https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/built-in-roles/ ] where you can select a role with the listCollections command